# Debugging WCF service library

Tags: .net, wcf, debugging

I'm trying to debug a wcf service that is part of a solution. Here is the exact setup that I have.

Solution

- Web Site (FileSystem web site,
  located in D:\project\web\ and so on)
- WCF Class Library (this is a normal
  class project that exposes
  Service/OperationContract with
  interface).

The website is hosting an application and I wanted to add a web service to it, so I added "webService.svc" to the root folder and added the appropriate config entries. When I run the website and navigate to http://localhost:5476/web/webService.svc I see the wsdl schema message as normal.

Now, in a different WPF application I add service reference to the above URL, it loads everything fine, no problem. I call the web service, it's simple Echo service, but the breakpoint I had put in the WCF Class Library isn't stopping, although I get proper results and everything. debug="true" in config is set, I tried loading the Symbols in Tools/Options, it didn't help. The breakpoint just isn't getting hit.

What am I missing?

Comment: In your WCF Solution, whilst debugging, select Attach to Process and attach to any w3wp.exe processes which aren't already attached.

Comment: I don't have any w3wp.exe process. I use VS2010, when I run the solution, it attaches to WebDev.WebServer40.exe, which is the ASP.NET Dev Server - Port 5476 that I can see in my tray.

Comment: When you are debugging, how is your breakpoint displayed in the VS2010 UI?  If the debug sees a matching assembly but has some problem it will appear as a yellow outline empty circle with an exclamation point.  If that's it, hover over and it will tell you why that breakpoint won't be hit.  If the BP is just its normal (non running) filled maroon circle, the debugger is not attached to the process hosting the lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Web Site Properties for your Web Site project, do you have "Always Start When Debugging" set to true?

Answer (score 0):

Check what you do not use "Release" build...
or check that your wcf client uses right wcf link